# error "System is not defined(…)" INTERNATIONALIZATION (I18N), angular-cli

Tags: angular

I was trying to learn this [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html) with JiT and angular-cli. I have got the following errors in browser console but no error in terminal to run/build the app.

Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined(…)

Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './locale/messages.fr.xlf!text'.(…)

[image]

My code in github https://github.com/sayedrakib/internationalization_project.git

I have added systemjs-text-plugin.js in the root folder, according to instruction in the tutorial.
File structure 
[image]

I think I have messed up with file path in some files, because I felt the assumed file structure in tutorial and angular-cli created file structure is not same.

Comment: Same here: `System is not defined`

Comment: Added this as an issue to angular.io docs section on https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/3238.

Answer (score 2):

I can see you are using angular-cli, than if you want to load 3party libery you need to work with angular-cli.json file.

First run at your app directory `npm install systemjs`
Second you need to add the path of systemjs at your angular-cli.json file.

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"
  ]
```

if you need to load other 3party libery just repeat the 2 stages.

Comment: This wont work as according to the instructions from Angular you should include a <script> tag with the code in your index.html. In this code system.js is used. But at the point that <script> tag is evaluated angular.cli did not yet included it to the page. So it´s still undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Took me ages to figure this out!

If you followed the documentation, change this:

1. Download [system.js](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs), but it in root (/app) and import it before the script tag.
2. In index.html remove the System.import('app')
3. Rename everything from System to SystemJS (index.html, i18n-provides.ts)

Finally it looks like this:

*index.html*

```
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>

  <script src="system.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Get the locale id somehow
    document.locale = 'es';

    // Map to the text plugin
    SystemJS.config({
      map: {
        text: 'systemjs-text-plugin.js'
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

*i18n-providers.ts*

```
export function getTranslationProviders(): Promise<Object[]> {
   [...]
}

declare let SystemJS: any;

function getTranslationsWithSystemJs(file: string) {
  return SystemJS.import(file + '!text'); // relies on text plugin
}
```

I opened a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14169) to update documentation.

Comment: But it is bad practise to include dependencies in your app as you don´t want to have them in GIT, isn´t it? Therefore this is no good solution to.

Comment: You can add it by npm of course. I guess the problem with the documentation is that systemjs is part of angular but not of angular-cli.

Comment: Ok. I tried to use this workaround but the textfile can´t be loaded. Error: GET http://localhost:4200/text 404 (Not Found). Did you make it work?